# How can I edit the place of the legends with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am having trouble in separating the legends in a ggplot2 graph with multiple layers. What my plot does is to fill different municipalities according to the number of textile companies present there and I also plot the plant localization with `geom_point`. My guess is to use `aes.override()` somehow, but I haven't been able to do this still. The solutions that I have read do not deal with a different variable for the plots detailed in the `aes()` of `geom_point()`.

If you want to test the code below, you could download the shapefile for the brazilian municipalities [here](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/Brasil/BR/br_municipios.zip), use `readOGR` and `fortify`, then choose to fill the municipalities with your preference with `fill` and set arbitrarily random points within Brazil for `geom_point()` creating a different variable, such as `lat_plant` and `long_plant` below. The `region` column below details brazilian regions -- in this case, the "1" details the northern region of Brazil.

## The Code

```
#setting the ggplot    
library(ggplot2)
    
gg2 < -ggplot(data = out[out$region =="1",], 
              aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.factor(companies))) + 
       geom_polygon() + 
       ggtitle("title") + 
       scale_fill_discrete(name = "Number of Textile Companies") +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
       theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
             legend.title = element_text(colour = "blue", size = 16, face = "bold")) 
      
#graph output

gg2 + 
geom_point(data = out[out$region =="1",], aes(x = long_plant, y = lat_plant), color = "red")
```

What I am getting as legend is this:

[image]

And I would like to separate it, detailing that the dots as localizations and the colors as the filling for the number of textile companies in the region.

Comment: I recommend putting some effort into building a reproducible example, if you expect good answers to your question

Comment: In your code the only aesthetic property mapped is `fill`, that's the reason why you end up with a legend like this. If you want to map the localizations you should set some aesthetic feature of `geom_point` for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I leave another option for you. hmgeiger treated the number of textile companies as factor. But, I rather treated the variable as a continuous variable. Since there is NO reproducible data, I created a sample data by myself. Here, I created random samples uing longitude and latitude of Brazil, and made sure that some data points stay in Brazil. `whatever2` contains data points staying in Brazil. I did a bit of trick here as well. I added a new column called `Factory location`. This is the dummy variable for adding color to data points in the final graphic. hmgeiger created `Dummy.var` that contains characters for you. I rather left `""` in this column since you may not want to see any text in legend.

For your legend issue, as Antonio mentioned and hmgeiger did, you need to add color in `aes()` in `geom_point()`. This solves it. I did a bit more thing for you. If you do not know how many factories exist in each municipal, you need to count the number of factories. I did the job using `poly.count()` in the `GISTools` package and created another data frame that contains the numbers of factories in each municipal.

When I drew the map, I had three layers. One is for the polygons and another for filling the polygons with colors. They are done with `geom_cartogram()` from the `ggalt` package. The key thing is that you need to have a common key column for `map_id`. `id` in the first `geom_cartogram()` and `ind` in the second `geom_cartogram()` are identical information. In `geom_point()` you need `color` in `aes()`. The legend has a continuous bar for the number of factories and a single dot for factory location. No text exists next to it. So this makes the legend tidy, I think.

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(GISTools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)

# Get polygon data for Brazil
brazil <- getData("GADM", country = "brazil", level = 1)

mymap <- fortify(brazil)

# Create dummy data staying in the polygons
# For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696382/removing-data-outside-country-map-boundary-in-r/47699405#47699405
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(long = runif(200, min = quantile(mymap$long)[1], max = quantile(mymap$long)[4]),
                     lat = runif(200, min = quantile(mymap$lat)[1], max = quantile(mymap$lat)[4]),
                     factory = paste("factory ", 1:200, sep = ""),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = mydata[, c("long", "lat")], data = mydata,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))


whatever <- spdf[!is.na(over(spdf, as(brazil, "SpatialPolygons"))), ]

whatever2 <- as.data.frame(whatever) %>%
             mutate(`Factory location` = "")


# Now I check how many data points (factories) exist in each polygon
# and create a data frame
factory.num <- poly.counts(pts = whatever, polys = brazil)
factory.num <- stack(factory.num)


ggplot() +
geom_cartogram(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id),
               map = mymap) +
geom_cartogram(data = factory.num, aes(fill = values, map_id = ind),
               map = mymap) +
geom_point(data = whatever2, aes(x = long, y = lat, color = `Factory location`)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Number of factories", colours = brewer.pal(5, "Greens")) +
coord_map() +
theme_map()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the link you posted to download the shape file is quite slow, at least to download to a US computer.

This link has downloads that work a lot better, and also shows how to read in shape data: https://dioferrari.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/plotting-maps-using-r-example-with-brazilian-municipal-level-data/

I made an example using the regions rather than municipalities data to keep it simple.

Data I used available for download here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64xLcn8DZfwakNMbHFLQWo4YzA/view?usp=sharing

```
#Load libraries.

library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

#Read in and format map data.

regions_OGR <- readOGR(dsn="/Users/hmgeiger/Downloads/regioes_2010",
layer = "regioes_2010")
map_regions <- spTransform(regions_OGR,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
map_regions_fortified <- fortify(map_regions)

#We make there be 0, 1, or 3 textile companies.
#map_regions_fortified is in  order by ID (region).
#So, we add a column with the number of textile companies 
#repeated the right number of times for how many of each region there is.

num_rows_per_region <- data.frame(table(map_regions_fortified$id))

map_regions_fortified <- data.frame(map_regions_fortified,
Num.factories = factor(rep(c(1,0,1,3,1),times=num_rows_per_region$Freq)))

#First, plot without any location dots.

ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=map_regions_fortified,
aes(x = long,y = lat, group=group, fill=Num.factories),colour="black")
```

Now, let's add the factory locations.

```
#Set latitude and longitude based on the number of factories per region.

factory_locations <- data.frame(long = c(-65,-55,-51,-44,-42,-38),
lat = c(-5,-15,-27,-7,-12,-8))

#Add a dummy variable, which then allows the colour of the dots 
#to be a part of the legend.

factory_locations <- data.frame(factory_locations,
Dummy.var = rep("One dot = one factory location",times=nrow(factory_locations)))

#Replot adding factory location dots.
#We will use black dots here since will be easier to see.

ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=map_regions_fortified,
aes(x = long,y = lat, group=group, fill=Num.factories),colour="black")       
+ geom_point(data = factory_locations,aes(x = long,y = lat,colour = Dummy.var)) 
+ scale_colour_manual(values="black") + labs(colour="")

#Bonus: Let's change the color vector to something more color-blind friendly.

mycol <- c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", 
"#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7","#490092")

ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=map_regions_fortified,
aes(x = long,y = lat, group=group, fill=Num.factories),colour="black")       
+ geom_point(data = factory_locations,aes(x = long,y = lat,colour = Dummy.var)) 
+ scale_colour_manual(values="black") + labs(colour="") 
+ scale_fill_manual(values=mycol)
```

[image]